# What's the best way to get all messages for all users?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

After doing some reading through the docs it seems like if you wanted to read all messages for all users in a Microsoft Exchange Online tenancy you need to do something like:

1. Get all users
2. For each user, get all mailFolders
3. For each mailFolder, get all messages

Is this the best way to get all messages, or is there some way to return all messages regardless of the mailFolder they are in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the second point and get all the messages in a user's mailbox by calling the endpoint:

```
GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/messages
```

Resource:

[List messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

Comment: Thanks that would be perfect but it looks like it doesn't support the delta function so it won't work for our use case. I'll mark your answer as correct though as I never specified I needed to get a delta